# Sum of nearest integers

Tags: number-theory

> Find $$N(n) = \left[\dfrac{3^2}{12} \right]+\left[\dfrac{4^2}{12} \right]+\left[\dfrac{5^2}{12} \right]+\cdots+ \left[\dfrac{(n+3)^2}{12} \right]$$ as a function of the residue of $n$ modulo $6$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer. Note: $[x]$ denotes the nearest integer to $x$.

I discovered that the fractional part of the parts inside the brackets is periodic with period $6$ since $\left\{\dfrac{(n+3)^2}{12}\right\} =\left\{\dfrac{(6k+n+3)^2}{12}\right\}$. I am not sure how this helps us determine the function $N(n)$ in terms of the residue of $n$ modulo $6$, but I think it helps.

Comment: So $[3.6]=4$ and $[2.3]=2$??

Comment: @S.C. That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be a non-negative integer.

We have
$$\small\begin{align}&\sum_{i=3}^{6m+3}\left[\frac{i^2}{12}\right]\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}\left[\frac{(6i-3)^2}{12}\right]+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left[\frac{(6i-2)^2}{12}\right]+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left[\frac{(6i-1)^2}{12}\right]+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left[\frac{(6i)^2}{12}\right]+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left[\frac{(6i+1)^2}{12}\right]+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left[\frac{(6i+2)^2}{12}\right]\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}(3i^2-3i+1)+\sum_{i=1}^{m}(3i^2-2i)+\sum_{i=1}^{m}(3i^2-i)+\sum_{i=1}^{m}(3i^2)+\sum_{i=1}^{m}(3i^2+i)+\sum_{i=1}^{m}(3i^2+2i)\\&=3(m+1)^2-3(m+1)+1+\sum_{i=1}^{m}(18i^2-3i+1)\\&=\frac{12m^3+21m^2+11m+2}{2}\end{align}$$
So, for $n=6m+k$,
$$N(n)=\frac{12m^3+21m^2+11m+2}{2}+r(m,k)$$
where 
$$r(m,0)=0,\quad r(m,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left[\frac{(6m+3+i)^2}{12}\right]\quad \text{for $k=1,2,3,4,5$}$$

Therefore,
$$N(6m)=\frac{12m^3+21m^2+11m+2}{2}$$
$$N(6m+1)=\frac{12m^3+27m^2+19m+4}{2}$$
$$N(6m+2)=\frac{12m^3+33m^2+29m+8}{2}$$
$$N(6m+3)=\frac{12m^3+39m^2+41m+14}{2}$$
$$N(6m+4)=\frac{12m^3+45m^2+55m+22}{2}$$
$$N(6m+5)=\frac{12m^3+51m^2+71m+32}{2}$$
from which we have
$$\color{red}{N(n)=\frac{2n^3+21n^2+66n+s}{72}}$$
where $s=72,55,56,63,64,47$ for $n\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5\pmod 6$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

For $0 \leq r \leq 5$, write $s_r=\{\dfrac{r^2}{12}\}$. We have $S_5=\dfrac{19}{12}$.

Let $n=6q+r$ with $0 \leq r \leq 5$.

Then $N(n)=\left(\sum_{k=3}^{6q+3}\dfrac{k^2}{12}\right)-\dfrac{19q}{12}+\sum_{k>6q+3}^{n+3}[\dfrac{k^2}{12}]$, which can be simplified.